auth()->check() and user() from jetstream livewire shows as undefined
I've installed Laravel v11 and Jetstream with Livewire, I tried to create a middleware to manage user roles and both user() and check() show as undefined
Here is the code:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        if (auth()->user()->role === 'admin') {
            return $next($request);
        }
        if (auth()->user()->role === 'student') {
            return $next($request);
        }

        if (auth()->user()->role !== $role) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}

